# Best way to get the Culture Info based on Country Code in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, kentico

currently I am developing a website that serves globally. 
What is the best way to get the culture info based on geo location data?
currently we are using Maxmind GeoIP. I cannot find a reliable answer on Google, so any advised from you guys is highly appreciated.

Comment: What location data is presented from the 3rd party?

Comment: Suppose you get the ISO2 country code, eg. CA for Canada; how are you going to decide between en-CA (speaking English) and fr-CA (speaking French)?

Comment: Hi Sir, the text is default to english, regardless of country. My goal is to get the currency code and the language code based on the culture info.

Answer (score 2):

you can get it from request instead of using IP - there is following header: accept-language

2 samples:
accept-language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Accept-Language: pl, fr-FR; q=0.8, fr; q=0.5, ru; q=0.3

using IP based might be misleading - e.g. when you're travelling you would get content in different language that your preferred one.

Comment: Hi Sir, the text is default to english, regardless of country. My goal is to get the currency code and the language code based on the culture info.

Comment: @NelsonNebre - when you create a CultureInfo object you can get currency code from following property: `NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol`. Regarding language code - it depends which one you're interested in the property `TwoLetterISOLanguageName`.